# Can you bypass stealing something if you have your companion inspect it?

Tags: fallout-4

I was in Diamond City at night with Strong and had him inspect an owned ammunition container belonging to Arturo. He took the items inside, and I traded with him and put them in my inventory. I then walked in front of a DC guard to see if he would become hostile, and he did not. I repeated this process multiple times, never crouched, and each time got off without anybody batting an eye.

Additionally, I had Strong take an item from off a table in front of Diamond City surplus, and Percy took it back in a calm manner (he did complain about 'having to put up with some people', but never became hostile).

Is this a bug in the game, being able to get away with theft if your companion inspects a container with the desired items inside? Or is it an interesting addition to the game?

EDIT: Had Strong steal a blood pack from Chem-I-Care. Guards became hostile, but did they become hostile because Solomon was not there to take it back?

Comment: When you got away with it, were you crouched and hidden or not in anyone's line of sight?

Comment: Just standing out in the open

Comment: that's interesting. I'm not sure and would have to check myself on this. You would think that the guards would at least become hostile towards Strong and take back the items.

Answer (score 2):

Carrying a stolen item doesn't flag a criminal activity; if Arturo or a guard didn't see Strong take the item, no theft occurred.

Please note that in an unmodded game, only certain companions with an alignment that allows them to do so will steal for you.  Strong and Cait both are aloof to human laws, so they'll do it, but Preston or Curie will not.